# How to get argument type hint in decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.5

How can I do the following:

```
import typing

def needs_parameter_type(decorated):
    def decorator(*args):
        [do something with the *type* of bar (aka args[0]), some_class]
        decorated(*args)
    return decorator

@needs_parameter_type
def foo(bar: SomeClass):
    …

foo(…)
```

The use case is to avoid the following repetition:

```
@needs_parameter_type(SomeClass)
def foo(bar: SomeClass):
    …
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints

Comment: are you just trying to make sure the type or the parameters is correct?

Comment: @JackHoman Nope, it's more complicated than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are stored in the `__annotations__` property of the function, you can access them by this:

```
def needs_parameter_type(decorated):
    def decorator(*args):
        print(decorated.__annotations__)
        decorated(*args)
    return decorator

@needs_parameter_type
def foo(bar: int):
   pass

foo(1)
#  {"bar": <class "int">}
```