# Using Python type hints to specify that a type should be just that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting

Can I use Python's type system like so?

```
def myFunc(type : type, any):
```

Such that the following are valid uses of the function.

```
myFunc(int, 4)
myFunc(float, "abc")
myFunt(myClass, [2, [4, "six"]])
```

But this is not.

```
myFunc(2, 3)
```

---

If this is not possible, can I achieve something similar either by requiring the object to have a constructor, or by requiring the type to be a class or a built in type?

```
def myFunc(type : has(__init__), any):
def myFunc(type : POD or Class, any):
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? isn't it apparent what variable type is being passed into the function? You could also just check the type after it's already been passed. Type definitions aren't needed in python.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type…?

Comment: I do really like duck typing, and how elegant Python is. I get the impression from all this that the answer is just not to and assume the user of the function can read the parameter name and from that input values with sensible properties themselves.

Comment: @alan2here. That's why you should write good documentation. Knowing a name and expected type is generally not much better than just knowing the name.

Comment: What's your end requirement here? What would a `myFunc` be in practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of what you want can be done by using decorators.

> can I achieve something similar either by requiring the object to have a constructor, or by requiring the type to be a class or a built in type

First define a decorator ( a function that does what you want, lets you process arguments or do whatever you want with the function before it is called) as such

```
def decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): # the function that does the checks
        # you can do the same for any keyword arguments
        for argument in args:
            if hasattr(argument, "__init__"): 
                print(f'Argument {argument} has an __init__ method')
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

And then you can apply it to any function

```
@decorator
def myFunction(some_argument):
    return None
```

For example if you call `myFunction` with an `int` you will get the following

```
In [18]: myFunction(3)
Argument 3 has an __init__ method
```

> Can I use Python's type system like so? ... Such that the following are valid uses of the function.

You can check inside the decorator the `__anotations__` of the function passed as noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298825/how-to-get-argument-type-hint-in-decorator) question and validate for each input. `__anotations__` returns a dictionary specifying with keys the names of the variables and values the type annotations. A simple example would be

```
def decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # {'a': <class 'str'>, 'b': <class 'int'>}
        type_hints = function.__annotations__ 
        
        # kwargs is a dictionary so
        # if a and b are parameters whose values are hello and
        # 2 then the dict is {a: "hello", b: 2}
        for keyword in kwargs:
            assert type(kwargs.get(keyword)) == type_hints.get(keyword)

        # also check on the list args
        for index, argument in enumerate(args):
            assert type(argument) == type_hints[list(type_hints)[index]]

        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def myFunc(a: str, b: int):
    return a, b
```

Now you can call the function as follows and it will only work if the type hints match the type of each function argument

```
In [42]: myFunc("hello", 1)
Out[42]: ('hello', 1)
In [43]: myFunc(1, 2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-8bd42ff057a5> in <module>
----> 1 myFunc(1, 2)
# ... the rest of the traceback
```

Comment: FWIW, it is not *required* to use a decorator if you're only interested in *static typing*. It's nice that the decorator can use the type annotations, but if you use type annotations, you typically want a static type checker to validate them and not a runtime decorator.

Comment: If you are writting a library, that does not have any speed requirements and you want the types to be correct, you cannot rely on "user" input. If you want to check before runtime if the function is called correctly then python is not the right choice, perhaps a compiled language that does this sort of validation would be better. Unless you have a powerfull IDE that does this sort of thing.

Comment: " If you want to check before runtime if the function is called correctly then python is not the right choice" The whole point of type hints was to allow third-party static type checkers to do just that. You can use `mypy` for example